# Ajax Filtering with GridView in Yii

Tags: ajax, gridview, filter, yii2, pjax

I want to use PJax in Yii Grid View, not with the associative filter that comes inside the Grid View, but with the Search Filter that's outside it, so it can filter the results inside.[image]

Here is the source of the index file:

```
<div class="cars-index">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>


<?php  echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create Cars', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>


<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        ['attribute' => 'code',
        'label' => 'Colour',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => 'colour',
        'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column){
            return ['style' => ' text-align: center; width: 100px;color:white;background-color:#'. $model -> code];
        },
        'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],
        'price',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Am I supposed to create an active form just for the part I want to filter? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You can't  simply add the filter to you table like this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
```

I suggest you use a proper action and a proper search function called by submit based on a specified active form

for **action form** eg:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'id' => 'search-form',
   'method' => 'post',
   'action' => ['controller/yourAction']
]); ?>
```

in the **controller**

```
 $model = new yourActiveForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search( [ 'yuorSearchModel'=> ['your_att1' => $model->yourValue1]]);
   }
```

then your render

Conforming to [yii2 doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html)

> Pjax only deals with the content enclosed between its begin() and
>   end() calls, called the body content of the widget. By default, any
>   link click or form submission (for those forms with data-pjax
>   attribute) within the body content will trigger an AJAX request. In
>   responding to the AJAX request, Pjax will send the updated body
>   content (based on the AJAX request) to the client which will replace
>   the old content with the new one. The browser's URL will then be
>   updated using pushState. The whole process requires no reloading of
>   the layout or resources (js, css).
>
> You may configure $linkSelector to specify which links should trigger
>   pjax, and configure $formSelector to specify which form submission may
>   trigger pjax.

You must add the

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?> 
 .... your active form

 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

and configure the proper $linkSelect and $formSelector

Comment: That's what I thought.. Thank you

Comment: :) I'm a fresh graduate training in a sw development company. I'm mainly a graphic designer, but I'm learning Yii2 as well thanks to people like you..
Regards

Comment: Using PJax for the filterModel inside the GridView is easy. But using external filter isn't working. I feel there is complication there.

Comment: Have you removed the accepted flag form this answer?

Comment: In fact yes, because I couldn't do anything. If I remove the flag maybe I'll get more help.. If nobody answers, I'll put it back ;)

Comment: yes ok. But is not difficult. Just do it step by step.1 )  Acrtive form submit for a proper Action 2) in actionController use the post data for set the search query param 3)  render your actual your view

Comment: This is already done. But I want to automatically refresh the gridview (using PJax) without pressing 'Search' button

Comment: I already did that, but I'll try to understand how to use the $linkSelect

Answer (score 0):

In your filter view:

```
<div id="myFilter">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'myFilterForm',
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => [...],
    ]); ?>
    ...
</div>
```

And make sure you render filter between `Pjax::begin` and `Pjax::end`

Yet here comes the trick. If your server does not respond within default timeout, `Pjax` gets ignored and page reloaded, so make sure the `timeout` is big enough:

```
<?php Pjax::begin([
    'id'=>'myGrid',
    'timeout' => 10000,                    // <------------ THIS !!!!!!!
    'formSelector' => '#myFilterForm'
]); ?>

<?= $this->render('myFilter', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Also in your controller, you might want to "reset" the search model, so only data from the request used are attributes actually used by `search`:

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $searchModel = new MySearch();

    if ($searchModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $searchModel = new MySearch(); // "reset"
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->post());
    } else {
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    }

    return $this->render('search', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!